# Converting UIColor to CGColor in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, colors, uicolor

This is the Obj-C code:

```
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]);
```

How do I write it in swift.

Comment: UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

Comment: `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,UIColor.lightGrayColor.CGColor)`

Answer (score 299, accepted):

```
// Original answer.
var newColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor

// Swift 3 version
var newColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 4+ version

```
UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
```

Answer (score 5):

Oddly enough, as Swift has evolved to 3.0 the answer has evolved as well. I ran across this while converting some Objective C code to Swift.  I hope this helps someone! :-) Here is what it is today:

```
context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.lightGray.cgColor)
```

And it's funny, this "light gray" answer is actually helping me debug some code too!  Thank iou!