# Using UIColor with CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor, rgba, cgcolor

I'm passing an RGB color to `shapeLayer.fillColor` and `shapeLayer.strokeColor`, and my code is crashing. Here's what I tried:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.fillColor = (UIColor(red: 57, green: 65, blue: 101, alpha: 1) as! CGColor)
shapeLayer.strokeColor = (UIColor(red: 57, green: 65, blue: 101, alpha: 1) as! CGColor)
```

If I write my RGB color as:

```
UIColor(red: 57, green: 65, blue: 101, alpha: 1)
```

Xcode gives me a warning to change it to:

```
(UIColor(red: 57, green: 65, blue: 101, alpha: 1) as! CGColor)
```

[image: error]

When I run Xcode's suggested fix, my app crashes. Why?

Comment: First issue: `57/255.0` it should be between 0 and 1, not 0 and 255. Second issue I'm not sure you can cast `UIColor` to `CGColor` like this. Instead: `shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 57/255.0, green: 65/255., blue: 101/255., alpha: 1).cgColor` See there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821785/converting-uicolor-to-cgcolor-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the parameters `red`,`green`, `blue` and `alpha` must be in range from 0.0 to 1.0

Secondly, you must pass the `cgColor` to `CGLayer`, e.g.

```
let color = UIColor(red: 57.0/255.0, green: 65.0/255.0, blue: 101.0/255.0, alpha: 1)
shapeLayer.fillColor = color.cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
```

Answer (score 2):

You are type casting `UIColor` as `CGColor` that is wrong. And RGB values must be the range from 0.0 to 1.0, Check the below code.

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: bounds.origin.x+60,y: bounds.origin.y+107), radius: CGFloat(6), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle:CGFloat(7), clockwise: true)

let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
circlePath.lineCapStyle = .round

let color = UIColor(red: 57.0/255.0, green: 65.0/255.0, blue: 101.0/255.0, alpha: 1).cgColor

shapeLayer.fillColor = color
shapeLayer.strokeColor = color
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fixing Your Code

You want something like this:

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red: 57, green: 65, blue: 101, alpha: 1).cgColor
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 57, green: 65, blue: 101, alpha: 1).cgColor
```

## How it Works

#### A Warning About Inheritance

Xcode warning you about *something* for that assignment is correct, because you're assigning a [`UIColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor) to a [`CGColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolor) property, but the "fix-me" suggestion is wrong. (Xcode might be doing this because it sees that the class names are similar, but not identical. It might be worth filing a radar.)

One place you'll see this a lot is typecasting a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass to the basic cell class, but that won't work here. `CGColor` does not inherit from `UIColor`, nor does `UIColor` inherit from `CGColor`. CGColor is a `CFTypeRef` and UIColor inherits from `NSObject.

#### One of These Is Not Like the Other

Now, why are these colors different?

`CG` stands for "Core Graphics" and is at a lower level than UIKit which defines the `UIColor` class. One color object is part of UIKit and the part of Core Graphics.

The documentation says that `UIColor` is:

> An object that stores color data and sometimes opacity (alpha value)."

A little further down, the overview says that UIColor represents itself internally as a `CGColor` within the predetermined color space.

`CGColor`, on the other hand, is:

> A set of components that define a color, with a color space specifying how to interpret them."

Conceptually, very similar, but not exactly the same thing. UIColor is defined in the sRGBA space ([as noted here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/color/)) but `CGColor` will contain info about what color space it's in.

Now, the animation layer you're using is part of Core Animation, which is yet another Apple framework. Core Animation isn't part of UIKit, and it's not "on top of" UIKit either, so its classes don't use `UIColor`. Core Animation uses `CGColor` for its representations of colors.

`UIColor` is so easy to instantiate, though, and we're in UIKit-land much of the time anyway. How can we customize `CALayer` and friends while working in our `UIView`s and `UIViewController`s? Luckily, `UIColor` exposes the `CGColor` version of itself, with the `.cgColor` property.

### A Note About Color Spaces

Some of the other answers note that you need to pass values between 0.0 and 1.0.  This is true, but it's relevant to note that as of iOS 10, Apple has added some wider-color capabilities to iOS.

This means that it's actually possible to pass in values less than 0.0 and greater than 1.0. From the [UIColor documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor#overview):

> When working in an extended color space, color values are not clamped to fit inside the color gamut, meaning that component values may be less than 0.0 or greater than 1.0. When displayed on an sRGB display, such colors are outside the gamut and will not be rendered accurately.

You probably won't need to worry about color spaces right now, but it's important to understand the fundamentals if you want to do things beyond showing a color onscreen. (Generating inverted or complementary colors are some examples.)

[Session 712 from WWDC 2016 (link)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/712/) covers this new API in depth, and I'd recommend that you take a look at it once you're more comfortable with the basics.

Finally, there's an [Apple Tech Note (TN2313)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2313/_index.html) that discusses this in more depth than I could ever imagine. If you want to learn a lot about colors and color spaces on iOS *and* macOS, read the tech note, entitled "Best Practices for Color Management in OS X and iOS."