# Application crash on assigning border width and color to textview in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am assigning border width and color to textview and it is crashing with this error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Here is my code:

```
class RatingViewController: UIViewController,UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var ratingTextView: UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ratingTextView.delegate = self
    ratingTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black as! CGColor
    ratingTextView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

}

Comment: `UIColor.black as! CGColor` this cause a crash, try this instead `UIColor.black.cgColor`

Comment: This is a good answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44892498/6057764)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are force-casting your *color* of type **UIColor** to an incompatible type **CGColor**.

Change `UIColor.black as! CGColor` to `UIColor.black.cgColor`.

UIColor's property `cgColor` converts between the two types in a safe way for you.

If you want to learn more about casting types then I'd recommend to read about **Inheritance** first.