# How to set night mode and day mode color in attributes inspector using IBInspectable?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to implement Dark mode in a huge project and i don't want to create outlets for each labels and views in order to change the colour as you know it's difficult.

i have created two colour choosers for UIView Subclass as an example using @IBInspectable.

-dayModeBGColor
-nightModeBGColor

But App crashes.

My code is as shown below.(Please don't suggest any other way)

```
import UIKit



class ThemeView: UIView {




    @IBInspectable var DarkColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {

        didSet{
            self.layer.backgroundColor = (self.DarkColor as! CGColor)
        }

    }


    @IBInspectable var DayColor: UIColor = UIColor.white {

        didSet{
            self.layer.backgroundColor = (self.DayColor as! CGColor)
        }

    }


    var selectedBGColor : UIColor = UIColor.white




    override func awakeFromNib() {


        if Theme.shared.isDarkMode == true {

            self.layer.backgroundColor = (DarkColor as! CGColor)

        }
        else{
            self.layer.backgroundColor = (DayColor as! CGColor)
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Change (DayColor as! CGColor) for DayColor.cgColor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting UIColor to CGColor in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821785/converting-uicolor-to-cgcolor-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is probably crashing because of the force-casting of `UIColor` to `CGColor`.

The correct way should be `self.layer.backgroundColor = self.DarkColor.cgColor`

Comment: But the background color doesn't change when i turn on/off dark mode.Is there anything i have to do with awakeFromNib. Do i have to do something to update or reload the current view?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in the `didSet` and see if the execution is reaching there ?

Comment: wait let me see

Comment: @JaseelCalicut For that you can check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47501154/3202193

Comment: no..its not what i am looking for bro..i just want to refresh the current view